# Problems redrawing a Canvas from scratch

Tags: android, canvas

I have a Canvas which I do a lot of drawing on, and at a later point I want to set it back to its original, un-scribbled image.

```
currentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(OCRMain.this.getResources(), R.drawable.ocrnew2, options);
currentBitmap = currentBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
mainImageToOCR.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
mainImageToOCR.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
canvasForDrawingBorderBoxes = new Canvas(currentBitmap);

//Draw on Canvas
//Now, this is what I had tried, but isn't working as desired as the scribbles I draw are staying visible.

canvasForDrawingBorderBoxes = new Canvas(currentBitmap);
mainImageToOCR.invalidate();
```

What's the proper way to accomplish refreshing the Canvas to its unmodified view? This is all happening on the UI thread, by the way.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Thanks to Mike M, I was able to modify my code once I understood what was happening behind the scenes. I created another Bitmap file, tempBitmap, set it to a copy of currentBitmap, and set the ImageView to that, as follows:

```
//At the beginning, before I draw on the Bitmap at all, I use tempBitmap to hold a copy of currentBitmap
tempBitmap = currentBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

//Do drawing stuff
currentBitmap = tempBitmap;
mainImageToOCR.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap);
```

One concern is that since the Bitmap is potentially of a large image, one that the user just took a photo of, duplicating it might cause memory issues. But it has yet to cause any errors to be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bitmap` is actually what you're drawing on. The `Canvas` is just what allows you to do so. If you want your image back to its original state, reload the `Bitmap`, and reset it for the `ImageView` and `Canvas`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've always been a bit uncertain as to the relationship to the Bitmap, the Canvas and the ImageView that holds them. The difficulty I'm having is that the Bitmap might originate from different places depending on a few things, so reloading it can be tricky. Is there any way to remove the various Rects which are drawn on it? Like, a removeAllViews() for an ImageView? Though I'm aware Rects aren't a type of View...

Comment: No. When the Canvas draws on the Bitmap object, it's directly setting values in what is essentially a huge array of `int`s. That's why Canvas exists - so you don't have to handle the tedious bit manipulation yourself. If you're concerned about reloading the Bitmap, load it first to a cache object, and make copies of that to draw on.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the insight there. Anyway, thanks to your help I got it working. I'll update my original post with the working code.